# Joomla new article not showing on url link

Tags: joomla3.0

When I create Joomla new article it is not showing on url, suppose my article alias name is **my-page** and my website name **firstsite** so I'm using  **localhost/firstsite/index.php/my-page** url

I have few default installed article which are showing properly but when I create new article it is not showing I am using Joomla 3.3.6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you link article to the menu item?

if you not. Go to current displaying menu click

```
Add Menu Item->Single Article
```

select your article and publish.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have linked it on menu, it is showing properly on that selected menu, but I want to access it by only using article alias name. like this **localhost/firstsite/index.php/my-page**  (_my-page_ is article alias name)

Comment: U can access only as  alias of menuitem. Check you menu item alias i try.

Comment: This is not true. we can access it using by **alias**, because I have some article which are by default stored when I joomla installed I can access it but when I creating new it is not working